# 70s/80s Radio drama about a young man who can't remember his name, stranded on a planet run by robots

Tags: story-identification, radio-play

This radio drama was about a young man who can't remember his name and is stranded on a planet run by robots. I think it's a mining operation. Earlier, it is revealed he was injured when his ship crashed/landed on this robot planet. So he had been unconscious for some time. He is frustrated to find that only robots populate the planet.

He comes across a girl and they both fight to get off the planet. They have some teleportation device they try to keep from the robots. At the end of one episode (the only one I ever heard) she tells him his real name. I think it was David. He and the girl get along but there is friction between them as well. He doesn't trust her.

At some point the planet is going to be attacked by another race. Also, there is some other creature/being with a very odd voice and manner of speaking. The boy and girl befriend him/her but leave that creature behind when they teleport away after activating the device. The boy hides the device in the rocks.

This radio drama seemed to be made in the 70s or 80s judging by the sound design. I heard it on a playlist on the now defunct radio streaming site ultimatescifi.com. It didn't seem to be taken from any of the series such as CBS Mystery Theater, X Minus One, Dimension X or any other series I know of.

Comment: This is a nice description but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, do you know what country this was broadcast in? What language was it? You also might want to consider [registering your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161).

Comment: Any recollection of the radio channels your plays aired on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm certain you're describing a radio dramatisation of [*Robot City: Odyssey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov%27s_Robot_City:_Odyssey) by Michael P. Kube-McDowell. ([*Robot City*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov%27s_Robot_City) is a series of Asimov-inspired works by other authors; *Odyssey* is the first book.)

- Amnesiac wakes up on a moon being mined by robots
- Adopts the name Derec (the name on his space suit) but is later revealed that his real name is David.
- Encounters a furry canine-like alien he names Wolruf
- Meets a female named Katherine with whom he has friction + chemistry (details of their shared past are revealed in later books). She tells him his real name, since she knows him from before the amnesia
- Has a teleportation device called a 'Key to Perihelion', which they hide in a crevice/alcove on a stone pyramid

Comment: I think that's it! I'll check it out. Thanks a million! I'd been looking for it under Asimov, but never found it. Now I know why.