# 70s SF book where the hero wakes up in a factory or prison but the computer won’t let him out

Tags: story-identification, books

From what I recall the hero wakes up in a factory or prison environment, however the computer that oversees the running of the place doesn't recognise him so won't let him out. I think at some point (could be a different book) he reaches some sort of teleportation device (possibly a goblet) at the top of a pyramid which transports him somewhere else.

Comment: Samuel R. Delaney.?

Comment: Please tell us whether the answer to [70s/80s Radio drama about a young man who can't remember his name, stranded on a planet run by robots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/215863) rings a bell - man waking up to some kind of overseeing by robots, teleportation and a pyramid involved.